# Discrepancy in JSON.stringify of date values in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I have this code in an HTML page:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(new Date()));
```

I'm including the latest [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) (2009-09-29 version) in my page to support older browsers without JSON.stringify().  I also have jquery-1.3.2.js included.  I believe in newer browsers with native JSON support, it just passes through to the native JSON feature.

Here's the results I get in different browsers:

```
IE 8 on Windows XP: "2010-02-07T21:39:32Z"
Chrome 4.0 on Windows XP: "2010-02-07T21:39:59Z"
Firefox 3.0 of Windows XP: "2010-02-07T21:40:41Z"
Chrome 4.0 on Ubuntu linux:  "2010-02-07T21:41:49Z"
Firefox 3.0 on Ubuntu linux:  "2010-02-07T21:42:44Z"
Chrome 4.0 on Mac OSX: "2010-02-07T21:43:56Z"
Safari on Mac OSX: "2010-02-07T21:45:21Z"
Firefox 3.5 on Mac OSX: "2010-02-07T21:44:10.101Z"
```

Notice the last one?  It contains milliseconds, and none of the others do.  I don't have FF3.5 installed on any other systems, but I'm assuming they would have the same results.

Is there something I can do to make all dates on all platforms stringify the same? My backend REST service can be configured with a format string to deserialize JSON dates, but it can't support multiple formats, just one.

Comment: FWIW, I just tested FF 3.6 on Win7 and it also gives milliseconds.

Comment: Relevant posting on Mozilla mailing list: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2008-October/001989.html

Comment: Wow, they implemented it this way few years ago?! I'm surprised this hasn't caused more problems. I appreciate trying to be standards conformant, but if everything else is doing it another way, at least give a configuration option to fallback.

Comment: Also Chrome 13 on Windows 7 shows the milliseconds. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got this working adding the following javascript:

```
// Added to make dates format to ISO8601
Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
    function f(n) {
        // Format integers to have at least two digits.
        return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
    }

    return this.getUTCFullYear()   + '-' +
         f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
         f(this.getUTCDate())      + 'T' +
         f(this.getUTCHours())     + ':' +
         f(this.getUTCMinutes())   + ':' +
         f(this.getUTCSeconds())   + '.' +
         f(this.getUTCMilliseconds())   + 'Z';
};
```

I'm sure this probably slows down the serialization, but it seems to make things consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You could also adjust json2.js a bit to always use its own `Date.prototype.toJSON` instead of a possible native one. Here I uncommented two lines and it works correctly:

```
// if (typeof Date.prototype.toJSON !== 'function') {

    Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {

        return isFinite(this.valueOf()) ?
               this.getUTCFullYear()   + '-' +
             f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
             f(this.getUTCDate())      + 'T' +
             f(this.getUTCHours())     + ':' +
             f(this.getUTCMinutes())   + ':' +
             f(this.getUTCSeconds())   + 'Z' : null;
    };

    String.prototype.toJSON =
    Number.prototype.toJSON =
    Boolean.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
        return this.valueOf();
    };
// }
```

Comment: Haha! I just posted this exact same thing only 5 seconds after you... I don't think you need to add the String, Number, and Boolean prototypes if you only want to customize Dates.

Answer (score 3):

//
You might want to consider beefing up the server, 
to recognize any valid ISO 8601 time format:

'2010-02-08T03:37:34.327Z'

'2010-02-08T03:38:06Z'

'2010-02-08T03:38+01:00'

'2010-02-08T03:34:18-05:00'

'2010-02-08T03:34Z'

'2010-02-08'

This is a method to convert any iso string to a javascript date object.
It could be used on the server with a little translation:

```
Date.from_iso= function(s){
    var D, M= [], hm, min= 0, d2,
    Rx=  /([\d:]+)(\.\d+)?(Z|(([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?)?$/;
    D= s.substring(0, 10).split('-');
    if(s.length> 11){
        M= s.substring(11).match(Rx) || [];
        if(M[1]) D= D.concat(M[1].split(':'));
        if(M[2]) D.push(Math.round(M[2]*1000));// msec
    }
    for(var i= 0, L= D.length; i<L; i++){
        D[i]= parseInt(D[i], 10);
    }
    D[1]-= 1;
    while(D.length< 6) D.push(0);
    if(M[4]){
        min= parseInt(M[6])*60+ parseInt(M[7], 10);// timezone not UTC
        if(M[5]== '+') min*= -1;
    }
    try{
        d2= Date.fromUTCArray(D);
        if(min) d2.setUTCMinutes(d2.getUTCMinutes()+ min);
    }
    catch(er){
        // bad input
    }
    return d2;
}
Date.fromUTCArray= function(A){
    var D= new Date;
    while(A.length < 7) A.push(0);
    var T= A.splice(3, A.length);
    D.setUTCFullYear.apply(D, A);
    D.setUTCHours.apply(D, T);
    return D;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it might come in handy in the client. I think I can use Joda Time to parse the different ISO formats on the server side.  I'm using Jersey with Jackson JSON handling for doing REST in a java server. By default, it attempts to convert from several different formats, but unfortunately only one of the ones I need. It has a way to override the format, but with only a single format string.  I'm sure there is a way I can get in deeper and override it better, but I'd have to put more time into doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) function in the Datepicker jQuery-UI plugin for jQuery to generate the format your server-side requires?

Comment: I'm passing an array of objects that contain dates.  This would mean going through the entire array and replacing the Date objects with string representations of them. I was hoping to not have to copy an existing array (generated by a 3rd-party tool) to my own version of it with strings for dates. However, this just might be what I need to do.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `formatDate` is not a jQuery function. Looks to be part of a datepicker control.