# Problem with date converting (send from JS -> .NET like a string)

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net

In my ASP .NET project we don't use any server controlls and codebehind files and work only with JavaScript, Asynch calls (send/recieve events to server with XMLHttpRequest) and SQL procedures.

So, i have a date in JavaScript, before i send it to ASP .NET like this: "Fri Aug 5 00:00:00 UTC+0400 2011" and i need to convert this on server or in JavaScript (before i send it) in format: "2011-08-05T00:00:00+04:00".

How is it better could be done?

### Thx.

Solution: use JSON.stringify.

Comment: see interesting post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2218564/303298.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this straightforward method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Covert js-date to ISO8601-string.
function DateToISO8601(dt) {

    if (dt == null) return null;

    var mnth = dt.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    if (mnth < 10) mnth = "0" + mnth;
    var day = dt.getUTCDate();
    if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
    var yr = dt.getUTCFullYear();
    var hrs = dt.getUTCHours();
    if (hrs < 10) hrs = "0" + hrs;
    var min = dt.getUTCMinutes();
    if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
    var secs = dt.getUTCSeconds();
    if (secs < 10) secs = "0" + secs;

    return yr + "-" + mnth + "-" + day + "T" + hrs + ":" + min + ":" + secs + "Z";
}

</script>
```

Comment: I've just found, that date converts using JSON.stringify, but thx.

Comment: @FSou1 you should consider posting your own answer and then accepting it.

Comment: see my answer. that is easier than this.

Answer (score 1):

JSON will serialize the JavaScript date for you if your ansyc calls are calling methods with a CLR DateTime as a parameter.  You do, however, have to do dateTime.ToLocalTime(), as the JSON value will be received in UTC.

For instance, if you're calling a WCF service or a PageMethod with the signature:

```
public bool DoSomething(DateTime dt)
```

Being called from the client side as:

```
PageMethods.DoSomething(dt, onSuccess, onFailure)
```

Or

```
var ws = new myNamespace.imyservice();
ws.DoSomething(dt, onSuccess, onFailure);
```

The time will be received in UTC on the server side, and you'll have to get back to local time:

```
dt.ToLocalTime()
```

I believe this is done by .NET auto-generated client service proxies due to the variable nature of client timezone/locale.

Answer (score 1):

use following code

```
var now = new Date();
now.format("isoDateTime");
```

Comment: this is the most easiest way of doing this. [more information..](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)