# Funky IE JSON conversions

Tags: json, angularjs, internet-explorer

When running our AngularJS app in IE11 everything looks great in the debugger, but when our app encodes the data as JSON to save to our database, we get bad results.

Our app obtains a record from our database, then some manipulation is done and then the data is saved back to the server from another model.

Here is the data I got back from the server in the setAttendanceGetSInfo() function below:

```
{"data":{"Start":"2014-10-16T19:36:00Z","End":"2014-10-16T19:37:00Z"},
```

This is the code used to "convert the data" to 3 properties in our model:

```
var setAttendanceGetSInfo = function (CourseId, PID) {
    return setAttendanceInfo(CourseId, PID)
    .then(function (result) {
        return $q.all([
            $http.get("../api/Axtra/getSInfo/" + model.event.Id),
            $http.get("../api/Axtra/GetStartAndEndDateTime/" + aRow.Rid)
        ]);
    }).then(function (result) {
        var r = result.data;
        var e = Date.fromISO(r.Start);
        var f = Date.fromISO(r.End);
        angular.extend(model.event, {
            examDate: new Date(e).toLocaleDateString(),
            examStartTime: (new Date(e)).toLocaleTimeString(),
            examEndTime: (new Date(f)).toLocaleTimeString()
        });
        return result.sInfo;
    });
};
```

fromISO is defined as:

```
(function(){
    var D= new Date('2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00');
    if(!D || +D!== 1307000069000){
        Date.fromISO= function(s){
            var day, tz,
            rx=/^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT ][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?$/,
            p= rx.exec(s) || [];
            if(p[1]){
                day= p[1].split(/\D/);
                for(var i= 0, L= day.length; i<L; i++){
                    day[i]= parseInt(day[i], 10) || 0;
                };
                day[1]-= 1;
                day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));
                if(!day.getDate()) return NaN;
                if(p[5]){
                    tz= (parseInt(p[5], 10)*60);
                    if(p[6]) tz+= parseInt(p[6], 10);
                    if(p[4]== '+') tz*= -1;
                    if(tz) day.setUTCMinutes(day.getUTCMinutes()+ tz);
                }
                return day;
            }
            return NaN;
        }
    }
    else{
        Date.fromISO= function(s){
            return new Date(s);
        }
    }
})()
```

Take a look at the screenshot of the event model data:

[image: Screemshot of Model]

But, if I eval the event model using `JSON.stringify(model.event)`, I get this:

```
{\"examDate\":\"?10?/?16?/?2014\",\"examStartTime\":\"?2?:?44?:?00? ?PM\",\"examEndTime\":\"?2?:?44?:?00? ?PM\"}
```

And this is the JSON encoded data that actually got stored on the DB:

```
"examDate":"¿10¿/¿16¿/¿2014","examStartTime":"¿2¿:¿36¿:¿00¿ ¿PM","examEndTime":"¿2¿:¿37¿:¿00¿ ¿PM"
```

What is wrong here and how can I fix this? It works exactly as designed in Chrome and Firefox. I have not yet tested on Safari or earlier versions of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I modified the fromISO prototype to this:

```
(function () {
    var D = new Date('2011-06-02T09:34:29+02:00');
    if (!D || +D !== 1307000069000) {
        Date.fromISO = function (s) {
            var D, M = [], hm, min = 0, d2,
                Rx = /([\d:]+)(\.\d+)?(Z|(([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?)?$/;
            D = s.substring(0, 10).split('-');
            if (s.length > 11) {
                M = s.substring(11).match(Rx) || [];
                if (M[1]) D = D.concat(M[1].split(':'));
                if (M[2]) D.push(Math.round(M[2] * 1000));// msec
            }
            for (var i = 0, L = D.length; i < L; i++) {
                D[i] = parseInt(D[i], 10);
            }
            D[1] -= 1;
            while (D.length < 6) D.push(0);
            if (M[4]) {
                min = parseInt(M[6]) * 60 + parseInt(M[7], 10);// timezone not UTC
                if (M[5] == '+') min *= -1;
            }
            try {
                d2 = Date.fromUTCArray(D);
                if (min) d2.setUTCMinutes(d2.getUTCMinutes() + min);
            }
            catch (er) {
                // bad input
            }
            return d2;
        }
    }
    else {
        Date.fromISO = function (s) {
            return new Date(s);
        }
    }

    Date.fromUTCArray = function (A) {
        var D = new Date;
        while (A.length < 7) A.push(0);
        var T = A.splice(3, A.length);
        D.setUTCFullYear.apply(D, A);
        D.setUTCHours.apply(D, T);
        return D;
    }

    Date.toJSON = function (key) {
        return isFinite(this.valueOf()) ?
               this.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
             f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
             f(this.getUTCDate()) + 'T' +
             f(this.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
             f(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' +
             f(this.getUTCSeconds()) + 'Z' : null;
    };
})()
```

Then I added moment.js and formatted the dates when they get stored:

```
var SaveAffRow = function () {
    // make sure dates on coursedate and event are correct.
    var cd = model.a.courseDate;
    var ed = model.event.examDate;
    var est = model.event.examStartTime;
    var eet = model.event.examEndTime;
    model.a.courseDate = moment(cd).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    model.event.examDate = moment(ed).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    model.event.examStartTime = moment(est).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A");
    model.event.examEndTime = moment(eet).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A");
    affRow.DocumentsJson = angular.toJson({a: model.a, event: model.event});

    var aff = {};

    if (affRow.Id != 0) 
        aff = affRow.$update({ Id: affRow.Id });
    else
        aff = affRow.$save({ Id: affRow.Id });
    return aff;
};
```

and when they get read (just in case they are messed up already):

```
var setAttendanceGetSInfo = function (CourseId, PID) {
    return setAttendanceInfo(CourseId, PID)
    .then(function (result) {
        return $q.all([
            $http.get("../api/Axtra/getSInfo/" + model.event.Id),
            $http.get("../api/Axtra/GetStartAndEndDateTime/" + aRow.Rid)
        ]);
    }).then(function (result) {
        var r = result.data;
        var e = Date.fromISO(r.Start);
        var f = Date.fromISO(r.End);
        angular.extend(model.event, {
            examDate: moment(e).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
            examStartTime: moment(e).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"),
            examEndTime: moment(f).format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A")
        });
        return result.sInfo;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The toJSON for the date class isn't defined perfectly the same for all browsers.

(You can see a related question here: [Discrepancy in JSON.stringify of date values in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218564/discrepancy-in-json-stringify-of-date-values-in-different-browsers)

I would suspect that you have a custom toJSON added to the Date prototype since your date string doesn't match the standard and that is likely where your issue is. Alternatively, you can use the Date toJSON recommended in the above post to solve your issues.